# Mongoose Schema TypeScript Error + Index signature for type string is missing

Tags: typescript, mongoose, inversifyjs

I am using inversify in my express API for dependency injection and I am trying to define my schema using `typescript 4.9.4` if I downgrade to `4.3.2` the error goes away but if possible I would love to figure this out.

**Interface**

```
export interface UserType {
    _id?: string
    email: string
    password: string
}

export interface UserModel extends UserType, Omit<Document, '_id'> {}
```

**Schema**

```
@injectable()
export class UserRepository
    extends GenericRepository<UserType, UserModel>
    implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public constructor(@inject(TYPES.DbClient) dbClient: DbClient) {
        super(
            dbClient,
            'users',
            new Schema({
                email: {
                    type: String,
                    trim: true,
                    required: true,
                    unique: true,
                    lowercase: true,
                },
                password: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                },
            }),
        )
    }
}
```

[image]